# Height of attributedText not returned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I need to display text in UITableViewCell and need to set the height of tableView. I am using the below methods to calculate the height of row dynamically. But the height is coming out to be a lot more than the actual height.

```
+ (CGFloat)getquestionLabelHeight:(NSNumber *)width text:(NSString *)text {
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake([width floatValue], CGFLOAT_MAX);
NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
CGSize boundingBox = [[ZUtility getAttributedText:text].string boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14]} context:context].size;
return boundingBox.height;
}
```

The reason I am converting text to attributed text is because normal text has html content and for line breaks '&nbsp' is present.

```
+(NSAttributedString *)getAttributedText:(NSString *)text {
NSMutableAttributedString *attrHTMLText = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil] mutableCopy];
[attrHTMLText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrHTMLText.length)];
[attrHTMLText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrHTMLText.length)];
return attrHTMLText;
}
```

[image]

For width 343, height is coming out to be 915 which is not accurate.

Comment: why you are not doing so with constraints ? @Astha Gupta

Answer (score 1):

You can use boundingRectWithSize

```
 NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"<p>The HTML <strong>&lt;strong&gt;</strong> element defines <strong>strong</strong>text, with added semantic importance.</p>"];

    // your attributed string
    CGFloat width = 200; // whatever your desired width is
    CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];;

    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```

Comment: How do I specify that content wrapping has to be of the type of wordWrapping?

Comment: by usinfing **NSMutableAttributedString**  not NSAttributedString  and add this   `NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                          value:paragraphStyle
                          range:NSMakeRange(0,[attrStr length])];`